# Pytest - Can't access imported class' attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, luigi

**Problem Summary:**
When trying to access class methods of a class/Luigi tasks that I am trying to test, it states that the class does not have the methods I am trying to use.

**More Detail:**
I am attempting to test a class/Luigi task I have written. I am trying to import the class I am testing into a test file to use its methods. However, when I try and import it, I can only access the class and not the methods inside it. None of its methods are accessible. I know I can import the class successfully because when I print an instance of it, it shows the object with correct attribute names.

**Here are any details I think might give context and help possibly lend a clue to resolving this:**

Project File Structure:

```
src
|
| - <folder containing code>
| | - foo.py
|
| - tests
| | - resources
|   | - count.csv
|
| | - test_example.py
| - pytest.ini
```

`foo.py` contains the class that I am testing. The class has the following structure:

```
import luigi

class Foo(luigi.Task):
   attr1 = luigi.Parameter()
   attr2 = luigi.ListParameter()

   def requires(self):
       None

   def output(self):
      <not important>

   def _helper_method_1():
      <CODE>

   def _helper_method_2():
      <CODE>

   def run(self):

      <code that uses all the helper methods>

            .
            .
            .
```

I am trying to run tests to test the helper methods in this class.

Here is the code I have in `test_example.py`:

```
import pytest
import sys
sys.path.append('../<folder containing code>/')
from <folder containing code>.foo import Foo

@pytest.fixture
def base():
    return Foo('hi',[])

def test_me(base):
    print(base)
    value = base._helper_method_1('./resources/count.csv')
    assert value == 3
```

Running pytest gives me the following error:

`FAILED tests/test_example.py::test_me - AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '_helper_method_1'`

And the following is printed:
`Foo(attr1='', attr2=[])`
This shows that the class is at least somewhat imported because it is mapping attribute names to the arguments I put in for the base fixture.

I have been stuck on this some time, trying different ways of importing the class in `test_example.py`:

Importing just the file:

```
sys.path.append('../<folder containing code>/')
from <folder containing code> import foo
```

Importing just the class:

```
sys.path.append('../<folder containing code>/')
from <folder containing code> import Foo
```

Please let me know if you have any recommendations or questions about information I may not have included that might help.

Thank you!

Comment: Does your helper method have that name, or can it be that you are using _double_ underscores? In this case the name would be mangled.

Comment: using the few code you provide to test it on my machine, I get `TypeError: _helper_method_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`. Once this error fixed by declaring arguments in `_helper_method_1`, the test fails but does not cause error. The problem is probably in a portion of the code you think is not relevant. Try to provide a fully functional minimal example reproducing your problem (something we could simply copy/paste and execute), it could help you to figure out by yourself what is the real problem.

Comment: I have the same problem where I'm able to import the class just fine but upon using it in pytest it's giving me a resounding `AttributeError: module 'xxx' has no attribute 'MyClass'`. Is pytest high or something?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `_helper_method_1` lacks a `self` parameter. In order to call `base._helper_method_1(...)`, you need to add `self`, or tag it with `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`. I would expect another error message, but perhaps pytest muddles it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. what I did was in your *tests/* folder create an empty **tests/conftest.py** file. It cleared everything up. I welcome explanations why this worked.